# From big-step to small-step semantics

Tags: operational-semantics, small-step-semantics

[Ciobaca: From Small-Step Semantics to Big-Step Semantics, Automatically](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/From-Small-Step-Semantics-to-Big-Step-Semantics%2C-Ciobaca/5092a6c72cf1395dc4ccbb1ea27896c5ae64d230?p2df)

describes how to go from small-step to big-step semantics.

I need to do the other way around: from big-step to small-step. Is there literature for this? What should I be careful of?

EXTENSION: I have a big-step operational semantics for a functional language and for my purposes I need to write a small-step operational semantics for it. Can you point to relevant scientific literature on how I should do this, what are the pitfalls?

Comment: Going from big-steps to small-steps is known as "the Art of Programming", IMO.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to expand a bit more on what you mean by "go from big-step to small-step semantics".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple articles on the matter.

[From Big-Step to Small-Step Semantics and Back with Interpreter Specialisation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02931)
and
[Automatic Transformation of a Big-Step Skeletal
Semantics into Small-Step](https://inria.hal.science/hal-02946930/file/RR-9363.pdf)

Also, if you need to write your own semantics for a functionnal language, you should have a look at pcf's semantics, for example [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/91556.91677). If you feel adventurous, start with a semantics for the lambda calculus and go your own way.